# Disabling hanging indentations with fill-paragraph

Tags: indentation, fill-paragraph

I want to be able to fill a whole paragraph with `fill-paragraph`, first line included, between the `left-margin` and `fill-column` values (`adaptive-fill-mode` is disabled).

I am able to do this, but I noticed that if the first line has an hanging indentation (meaning it has a different indentation from the `left-margin` variable), I am unable to remove it, unless I manually go to the first line, removing it. I want to be able to remove the hanging indentation by just running `fill-paragraph`.

Example of hanging indentation, considering `left-margin` equal to 0:

```
  this is an example
of an hanging indentation
in a paragraph.
```

What I want to happen when I run `fill-paragraph`:

```
this is an example
of an hanging indentation
in a paragraph.
```

But I am unable to recreate such a behaviour. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Filling.html#Filling) on the topic barely mentions hanging indentations, and is not helpful on how to disable them.

Comment: Minor nit: That's not a hanging indentation. A hanging indentation is when the first line is *not* indented, while subsequent lines *are*.

Comment: I see, so maybe that is the reason I can't find docs on the topic. Do you know the name of such a behaviour?

Comment: Your sample paragraph only has regular indentation. It's not uncommon, after all, to indent the first line of a paragraph, which I assume is why `fill-paragraph` preserves any indentation it finds in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like there is no option to remove them, I created a hack to work around this.

```
(defun my-fill-paragraph (&optional justify)
  (interactive "P")
  (backward-paragraph)
  (skip-chars-forward " \n\t")
  (indent-to-left-margin)
  (fill-paragraph))

(setq fill-paragraph-function 'my-fill-paragraph)
```

What this does is moving at the beginning of the paragraph, skip any whitespace and newline and then indent the first line of the paragraph to `left-margin`. After that, it just runs `fill-paragraph` normally with the new indentation.